# php sqlite3 - get result from prepared statement

Tags: php, sqlite, prepared-statement

All the examples and documentation didnt really help or even offer an example for this so I m gonna ask here:

```
$db = new SQLite3(database.db);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(uid)  FROM kunden WHERE date = :date');
$stmt->bindValue(':ldate',$today,SQLITE3_TEXT);
$result =  $stmt->execute;
```

How can I get the result from that prepared statement? I know execute is not supposed to return a result. I tried using query and query_single but that didnt work. var_dump($result->fetchArray()); also didnt work. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLite3Stmt::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php) is a function, and needs to be called as such:

```
$db = new SQLite3('database.db');
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(uid)  FROM kunden WHERE date = :date');
$stmt->bindValue(':ldate',$today,SQLITE3_TEXT);
$result =  $stmt->execute();
```

You can then fetch the result like this:

```
$array = $result->fetchArray();
echo $array['COUNT(uid)'];
```